Create a Refinable managed property which contain a Date field + choice field
I have a sharepoint online date field named DueDate of type Date/Time that allow to enter Date Only (without time).
And i choice field named DueDatetime with these values:-
12:00 AM

12:30 AM

1:00 AM

1:30 AM

2:00 AM

2:30 AM

3:00 AM

3:30 AM

4:00 AM

4:30 AM

5:00 AM

5:30 AM

6:00 AM

6:30 AM

7:00 AM

7:30 AM

8:00 AM

8:30 AM

9:00 AM

9:30 AM

10:00 AM

10:30 AM

11:00 AM

11:30 AM

12:00 PM

12:30 PM

1:00 PM

1:30 PM

2:00 PM

2:30 PM

3:00 PM

3:30 PM

4:00 PM

4:30 PM

5:00 PM

5:30 PM

6:00 PM

6:30 PM

7:00 PM

7:30 PM

8:00 PM

8:30 PM

9:00 PM

9:30 PM

10:00 PM

10:30 PM

11:00 PM

11:30 PM

now can i create a refinable managed property that combine the values of both fields to generate a date & time field? so i can search, filter and sort items based on this refianble value?
so if i have a combination of the 2 columns as follow:-
22 August 2024 9:00 pm
22 August 2023 11:00 am
and i sort them descending then
22 August 2024 9:00 pm
should be shown before
22 August 2023 11:00 am
is this possible? to manage inside sharepoint search?

Per my test, it is not possible to create a refinable managed property that combine the values of both fields to generate as a date & time field.
In the SharePoint search, you could use refinable managed property equal to a value to filter search results. It can be a value from one filed but cannot a combined value form two fields.
So, as a workaround, you could use two refinable managed properties to filter search results or create a date and time field as refinable managed property to filter search results.
